Error of Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
I'm using Sitecore 9.3 and getting many error logs and the site loads very slow locally.
ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.XConnect.DefaultXdbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.AsyncPoolScheduler`2..ctor(IAsyncProcessingPool`1 pool, IXdbContextFactory xdbContextFactory, ExpandOptions options, Int16 maxBatchSize, BaseLog log)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregationAgent.<ExecuteCoreAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Agent.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<ExecuteAgentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<RunAsync>d__26.MoveNext()


ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.XConnect.DefaultXdbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly()
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Any idea how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

It looks like there could be a permission issue with the Xconnect certificate.
Try out the below steps:

Window + R to open run window and type mmc.
Go to File menu and click on Add/Remove Snap-in...
Select certificates and click on Add button and select Computer account then click Next > Finish > Ok button.
Go to Personal > Certificate and right-click your .xconnect certificate.
Go to All Tasks > Manage Private Keys.
If LOCAL SERVICE and NETWORK SERVICE are not listed under the Group or user names then add them.

Now try to restart your IIS.
Hope it helps!

Thank you. It is working fine now.

In order to address this issue, you can check the access permissions to the XConnect certificate.

Open the Computer Certificates tab from the search panel.



Go to the Personal->Certificates section and search for the xConnect certificate for the site.
Then right click on the certificate and click on All Tasks > Manage Private Keys option.



Make sure all the below app pool roles are added onto the certificate.


IUSR
Network Service
IIS_IUSRS
Service
Local Service
IIS AppPool\XConnect Site App Pool
IIS AppPool\Site App Pool


Once the above changes are made, you can restart xConnect and Site Application pools.
You can find more details on the same here:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0719199
Hope this helps!!!
